.vscode no longer in a workspace
I am reading VS Code USER GUIDE and I see that in the "Single-folder workspaces" section there is a .vscode folder file in the workspace. I created my workspace as described in the "How do I open a VS Code "workspace"?" section however, I do ot see any .vscode folder in my worskapce. Is this user guide outdated? I am using the lates VS Code:
Version: 1.88.1 (user setup)
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:41:02.734Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

The folder will be created as soon as you alter a workspace-specific setting or workspace-specific configuration (such as a debug profile)
Example:
Go to "Settings"
Go to "Workspace" tab
Edit one setting such as "Font Size"
Save

The .vscode folder will be created as well as a settings.json file

